# Electromagnetic Unruh effect?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, unruh-effect

The Unruh temperature is given by
$$T=\frac{\hbar\ a}{2\pi c k_B}.$$

If we have an electron field with charge $e$ and mass $m_e$ acted on by an electromagnetic field $\vec{E}$ then very naively maybe we can write a Newton's 2nd law equation

$$\vec{E}\ e=m_e\ \vec{a}.$$

Substituting the magnitude of the acceleration $a$ into the Unruh formula we get

$$T=\frac{\hbar}{2\pi c k_B}\frac{E\ e}{m_e}.$$

If we take the electric field strength $E=1$ MV/m then the Unruh temperature is

$$T\approx 10^{-2}\ \hbox{K}.$$

Perhaps this temperature could be measured?

Comment: It would be a matter of detecting individual photons in the 30cm/1GHz range that is a tough task.

Comment: 1. Why do you say "electron field" and not simply *electron*? There's no such thing as "an electron field with charge $e$ and mass $m$". 2. It's not clear what you are computing - the formula for Unruh temperature is the formula for the temperature of the thermal radiation an observer accelerated with the acceleration $a$ sees. If you just take some electron and accelerate it in a field, it's not clear *what* you want to measure - you'd have to accelerate your measurement device, not some random electron, to see Unruh radiation with it.

Comment: The Unruh radiation is assumed to be similar to Hawking radiation from a black hole. In that case the observer does not have to be accelerating - he can be far away observing the radiation.

Comment: As I understand it one can think of electron-positron pairs fleetingly popping out of the vacuum and then annihilating. If there is an applied electric field then they will be accelerated apart so that they will take slightly longer to annihilate. Thus I could imagine the properties of the vacuum changing in such a circumstance. If the electric field is at the Schwinger limit $10^{18}$ V/m then I guess that real particles can pop out of the vacuum. I don't know where the energy comes from  - from the vacuum itself?