# Schwinger effect verified by Unruh temperature?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, virtual-particles, unruh-effect

According to https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4569, equation.(2.15), the Schwinger electron-positron pair production rate in Minkowski space, $N_S$, is given in natural units by
$$N_S\sim\exp(-\frac{m}{2T_U})$$
where the `Unruh temperature for the accelerating charge', $T_U$, is given by
$$T_U=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{qE}{m}$$
where $q$ is the electron charge, $m$ is the electron mass and $E$ is the applied electric field.

In principle, could the Schwinger effect be confirmed by measuring the temperature $T_U$ rather than trying to detect electron-positron pairs?

In SI Units:
$$T_U = \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{\hbar}{c k_B}\frac{q E}{m}$$
If the static electric field $E=1$ MV/m then the Unruh temperature $T_U\sim 10^{-3}$K.

Could one use [laser cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_cooling) to cool atoms down to the millikelvin range and then apply a large electric field of say $10^6$ V/m? The atoms should warm up due to the Unruh temperature, $T_U \sim 10^{-3}$K, induced by the static electric field. Perhaps this temperature rise would cause quantum decoherence that could then be detected?

(Previous post [Electromagnetic Unruh/Hawking effect? (Improved argument)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/370096/))